# Fixing column headers in FlexiGrid

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Can anyone tell whether we can fix first two columns on FlexiGrid..?

My requirement is, need to fix 2 columns and all the table headers. I have tried many jquery based plugins, found BI Grid as the right one but having some UI issues.

http://www.bi-grid.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexigrid does not support fixed columns.
You can try data tables plug-in, it supports fixed header and colums, check his example:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/two_columns.html